# Function invocation in `std::bind`

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

**TLDR**: How does `std::bind()` actually work when calling a member function with an instance of a class or a `this` pointer of the class?

**Notes**:

1. I know what a function adapter and a function object are.
2. I know `this` is implicitly used as the first argument when calling a member function
3. I know how `std::placeholder` works
4. I know how to call a member function in a more ordinary way, like `(instance.*ptr)()`

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
  void test(const std::string &info) { std::cout << info << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  Test test;

  // call with instance
  std::bind(&Test::test, std::placeholders::_1, "call with instance")(test);
  // call with `this`
  std::bind(&Test::test, std::placeholders::_1,
            "call with `this` pointer")(&test);
}
```

This code works fine on my platform. So, I guess, either `std::bind()` has done the job to distinguish an instance and a pointer, or I misunderstood something.

Comment: The "magic" is in `INVOKE`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks a lot! I'd really appreciate if you can provide a formal answer so that I can close this question to save others' time

Comment: @NathanOliver -- just to be clear: `INVOKE` is not a macro, despite being capitalized. It's not C++. It's a term of art in the C++ standard, used to consolidate the description of how function objects get invoked, which is needed in several places in the standard. There is also a template, `std::invoke`, added in C++17, which encodes the requirements described by `INVOKE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)  mentions, when `f` of `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is a pointer to member function of class `T`:

1. if `t1` is an instance of class `T` or base class of `T`, it will be equivalent to: `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)`
2. if `t1` is a specialization of `std::reference_wrapper`, it will be equivalent to: `t1.get().*f`
3. otherwise, it will be `(*t1).*f`

For more details, please read the doc.